# Multiple iOS animations work only for first view

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I've a strange animation issue with iOS animation.
I am trying to animate moving from bottom to top UITableView cells.
But the animation works only for the first cell. All other cells remains at their positions (at bottom of table) (nevertheless reported frames changed).

Any ideas? Here is my piece of code:

```
- (float)runCellAnimations {
    NSTimeInterval animationDelay = 0.0;
    NSArray *cells = [tableView visibleCells];

    for (GTMapLocationCell *cell in cells) {

        CGPoint origin = cell.origin;
        cell.origin = CGPointMake(cell.origin.x, CGRectGetHeight(tableView.bounds));

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Cell Location" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:GT_CELL_ANIMATION_DURATION];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:animationDelay];
        cell.origin = origin;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        animationDelay += GT_CELL_ANIMATION_INTERVAL;

    }

    return (animationDelay-GT_CELL_ANIMATION_INTERVAL)+GT_CELL_ANIMATION_DURATION;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you the block-based animation instead.

Comment: I tried [UIView animateWithDuration ...]. This one behaves as earlier. Completion block was never called.

Comment: it is not possible, you did something wrong, post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [UIView beginAnimations:] and animation setter methods before the for loop, and call [UIView commitAnimations] method after the scope of the for loop.

Our suggestion is simply making changes for each cell but executing just one animation.